# Regex on Perl Queries using getopt arguments

Tags: sql, regex, perl

I am doing a number of exercises to increase my aptitude in Perl, and have run into a situation where I need some guidance.

Currently I a script that takes a command line argument using getopt and feeds it into function1. Function1 then takes the search, and performs a SQL query on a table I've setup and returns the results as a hash_ref. The output from function1 is then assigned to a variable which is fed into function2. Function2 takes the hash_ref, prints the dereferenced results, and returns a value or -1 or 0 depending on the hash_ref has keys. That number is then fed out, and if a -1 is printed it reports that no results were found for the search.

I now need to modify my script, by adding in additional command-line arguments using getopt, and then feeding the results through Regex for each argument.

My question is fundamentally... what is the best way to do this? I'm extremely new at PERL and regex in general, but I think I can figure out the regex syntax. Should I assign the regex test before I pass it to my first function? Should I do it in the SQL query itself (is that even possible? I can't find much Regex/Perl/SQL documentation for what I'm trying to do).

I can add my code if needed, but I'd prefer just general guidance so I can figure it out myself.

Comment: Do you mean: How can I use regular expression to validate that the arguments are in the correct format?

Comment: Basically my query is on a table of professional athletes, jersey numbers, and the sport they play. If I pass the script an argument with the 'Sport' it prints out all players who play that using the -s argument. If I pass it an integer -i I want it to print out all players whose names are less characters then the number. If I pass it a letter -l I want it to print out all players whose names are earlier in the alphabet than the the letter passed. I can figure out the regex for those critera, but I want to know how to pass those regex to my SQL query correctly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need a regex for this.

```
sub getAthletes {

  my($sport_arg, $number_arg) = @_

  $whereclause = " 1=1 ";  # start it with this

  if($sport_arg) {
    $whereclause .= " and sport = '$sport_arg'" ;
  }
  if($number_arg) {
    $whereclause .= " and jerseynum = $number_arg ";
  }
  $query = "SELECT * FROM ATHLETES WHERE $whereclause";

  print STDERR "Your query, friend:  $query\n";

  ... rest of your program here
}

GetOptions("s=s", \$sport_arg,
           "i=s", \$number_arg);

getAthletes($sport_arg, $number_arg);
```